# splitting the data in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am very new to Excel macros. I have below data in Excel:

```
Col1 Col2       col3    col4  Col5
32    000-001                   1
32    002-001                   100
32    005-000                   20
```

and so on. I have 6313 rows in my excel spreadsheet.

I want to split col2 and put the first three numbers before hyphen in col3 and last three numbers in col4. I also want to remove hyphen from col2 so my final output will be like this:

```
col1   col2     col3    col4    col5
32    000001    000      001    1
32    002001    002      001    100
332   005000    005      000    20
```

This is what I already tried. I tried to replace Hyphen with empty space and then I lost all the leading zeros. I don't want to lose all the leading zero from col2.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub aljali()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long

    Range("A:E").NumberFormat = "@"
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To N
        Cells(i, "B").Value = Replace(Cells(i, "B").Value, "-", "")
        Cells(i, "C").Value = Left(Cells(i, "B").Value, 3)
        Cells(i, "D").Value = Right(Cells(i, "B").Value, 3)
    Next i
End Sub
```

**NOTE:**

The key to this is setting the format of the cells to *Text*.  This facilitates the preservation of those leading zeros.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `Col1` is in A1: Move ColumnB to ColumnC, split Text to Columns with `-` as delimiter (choose Text for both columns) then in B2 and copied down to suit:

```
=C2&D2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
With Worksheets("sheet8")
    For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        With .Cells(i, "B")
            .Resize(1, 3).NumberFormat = "@"
            .Resize(1, 3) = Array(Replace(.Value2, Chr(45), vbNullString), _
                           Split(.Value2, Chr(45))(0), _
                           Split(.Value2, Chr(45))(1))
        End With
    Next i
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

If doing this outside of VBA is an option (*tagged* `Excel-Formula`), you could make use of the following three functions: `Left`, `Right`, and `Substitute`.

You will need to add an extra column to implement this.

[image]

Which will yield the following results:

[image]